# Plot bars next to each of subplots in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I'd like to visualize 2D data with bar charts where I want to show totals per X and also ratios of Y's within each X. My idea was a nested bar plot. So I started with the ratio's of Y within each X:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import itertools as itoo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random.seed(0)
s=pd.Series([random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100)],
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x,y) for x,y in itoo.product(range(10), repeat=2)], names=list("xy")))
fig, axes=plt.subplots(10, sharex=True) # no sharey since only ratios important
for x, ax in zip(range(10), reversed(axes)):
    sx=s[x]
    ax.bar(sx.index, sx, align="center")
    ax.set_xticks(range(10))
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax.set_ylabel(x)
    tot=sx.sum()
    #plot label `x` and a single hbar(width=tot) right next to plot?;
```

[image]

How can I add horizontal bars for totals on the right of each bar plot?

Basically it will look like a full hbar plot of totals for each X on the right of the whole bar plot set (it should also have a labeled xaxis). It's just important to align these bars with the corresponding bar subplots. I'd also like labels per "row" between the subplot and the horizontal bar. I'd also like to make the given subplots (and thus bar) much more narrow.

Comment: If using `subplot` doesn't do it for you, perhaps you can use [gridspec](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/gridspec.html)?

Comment: It would be challenging to perfectly align the totals bar plot with each row?

Comment: With gridspec it would not be hard, no.

Comment: How would I assign the bars between each other and also add an axis at the bottom? I'd have to simulate a bar plot, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others said, using `gridspec` can do it for you. Here's an example of how to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import itertools as itoo
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
from numpy import arange,array

random.seed(0)
s=pd.Series([random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(100)],
             index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(x,y) for x,y in itoo.product(range(10), repeat=2)], names=list("xy")))

fig=plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0,wspace=0.5)
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(10,8)

axes=[fig.add_subplot(gs[0,:6])]
[axes.append(fig.add_subplot(gs[i,:6],sharex=axes[0])) for i in range(1,10)]

tot=[] # Keep track of totals

for x, ax in zip(range(10), reversed(axes)):
    sx=s[x]
    ax.bar(sx.index, sx, align="center")
    ax.set_xticks(range(10))
    ax.yaxis.set_ticks([])
    ax.set_ylabel(x)
    tot.append(sx.sum())

#plot label `x` and a single hbar(width=tot) right next to plot
axh=fig.add_subplot(gs[:,6:])
axh.barh(arange(10)-0.4,array(tot))
axh.set_yticks(range(10))
axh.set_ylim(-0.5,9.5)
fig.savefig('test.pdf')
```

And here's what the output looks like:

[image: using gridspec]

Comment: I was worried that such an approach wouldn't be clean since if I had many more rows, they might not align anymore? But I guess I have to live with that or it gets really complicating?

Comment: I think by removing the space between the vertical bar plots (hspace=0) like I did above helps with that alignment, but YMMV